# need wordpress plugin to show 3 type of different kind of text, image and 2 buttons

Tags: plugins, wordpress

I have slider image on http://techturners.com/arman-badwal/ page in "featured work" section. I need plugin to create dynamic slider like image in section.I use many sliders like cyclone-slider but they show only title, description and image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not really understandable, but I think you are looking for this, it's a really good slider with a lot of functionality.

[Revolution Slider](http://codecanyon.net/item/slider-revolution-responsive-wordpress-plugin/2751380)

Comment: actually i need a slider which have one image, 2 buttons, 3 different text layers as shown in the link.According to suggestion revolution slider have huge set of functionalities that fulfill my requirements. Thank you so much